# Google Scatter chart duplicates same domain (x-axis) values

Tags: charts, google-visualization

When I use a Scatter Chart with domain `type:string` the values on the x-axis get duplicated.
For example:

```
    dataTable.addRows([
                        [ 'A',1],
                        [ 'A',2],                                         
                        ]),
```

This will show A twice on the x-axis. 
Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug with Scatter Chart and string domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not a bug, by default...

if possible, a discrete axis (`'string'` values) will show every row label, even if they repeat...
it will also plot the values for each row label on a separate x coordinate

---

if your chart requires the values for repeated row labels to be plotted on the same x coordinate,
add data table columns, or series, for each additional value, e.g.

```
['A', 1, 2],
['B', 1, 2],
```

note: by default each series will have a different color,
if all points should be the same color, override using the `colors` option
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['row label', 'y0', 'y1'],
    ['A', 1, 2],
    ['B', 1, 2]
  ]);

  var options = {
    colors: ['red', 'red']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

if separate x coordinates are ok, and you just don't want the labels to repeat,
*and* the labels repeat in a consistent manner (always 2 A's, 2 B's, etc.)
you can use config option `hAxis.showTextEvery`
this will show every other row label...

```
hAxis: {
  showTextEvery: 2
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['row label', 'y0'],
    ['A', 1],
    ['A', 2],
    ['B', 1],
    ['B', 2]
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      showTextEvery: 2
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

if the axis should behave similar to a continuous axis (`'number'`, `'date'` values),
but show strings instead, use numbers instead of strings,
and use object notation to override the formatted values

with object notation, you can provide the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)

```
[{v: 1, f: 'A'}, 1],
[{v: 1, f: 'A'}, 2],
[{v: 2, f: 'B'}, 1],
[{v: 2, f: 'B'}, 2],
```

using object notation in the data table will display `'A'` in the default tooltip

for axis labels, you will need to provide your own `ticks` using the same notation

```
hAxis: {
  ticks: [
    {v: 1, f: 'A'},
    {v: 2, f: 'B'}
  ]
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['row label', 'y0'],
    [{v: 1, f: 'A'}, 1],
    [{v: 1, f: 'A'}, 2],
    [{v: 2, f: 'B'}, 1],
    [{v: 2, f: 'B'}, 2],
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: ''},   // add extra room
        {v: 1, f: 'A'},
        {v: 2, f: 'B'},
        {v: 3, f: ''}    // add extra room
      ]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I came up with the same solution to use different series. But I do think this default behavior is a bit strange.. Anyway thanks for your help!